# jira home directory error on linux "Could not create jira.home directory"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jira

I have installed jira on my remote vps running ubuntu server, and when I visit the jira url, i get the following:

```
 Could not create jira.home directory '/var/atlassian/application-data/jira'. Please see Setting your JIRA Home Directory for more information on how to set up your JIRA home directory.
```

i have installed it as root.

```
root@myvpsip:/var/atlassian/application-data# ls -lh
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 17 22:29 jira
```

could somebody help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk is out of space, or you are running the installer as an account which does not have the rights to create and/or use the directory specified in the error message. Please check with `ps` the account name and set appropriate permissions for JIRA home folder.